# How to use wikipedia API to parse through a list of links and retrieve data from them?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I have a wikipedia page that contains links (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_countries_and_territories).  I want to go through all of those links that then retrieve the list of countries that are listed.

I have been able to retrieve all the links with BeautifulSoup and could just go through the links and use beautifulsoup to do it, but I want to use this scraper for various things and was wondering if there was a way to do this more easily and faster with the wikipedia API.

Comment: Consider using a wikipedia dump, or DBpedia (P.S. scraping is not data mining)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links gets a list of all links on the provided pages. you can use this list as [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators)  to retrieve the listed  page properties, There are also [client libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python)